# Find lost acer android tablet without a tracker installed

Tags: acer-iconia-a500

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find a lost phone or help people return it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/how-can-i-find-a-lost-phone-or-help-people-return-it)
>   [My phone was just stolen an hour or so ago. Are there any options for tracking?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18644/my-phone-was-just-stolen-an-hour-or-so-ago-are-there-any-options-for-tracking)

How do you find your lost Acer Android Tablet a500 Iconia Tab without a tracker installed?

Comment: I lost my Acer Android Tablet a500 Iconia Tab outside and there is no GPS TRACKER OR ANY SORT OF TRACKER THAT I KNOW OF I THINK and I need all the help I can get to get my device back, It means alot to me. So please feel free to give some advice or a solution to deal with this messed up plot. Thank you. All your effort will be HIGHLY APPRECIATED!     ndndjfnsjdnfjsdnf

Comment: Possible dupes: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/how-can-i-find-a-lost-phone-or-help-people-return-it http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26372/find-lost-device-without-gmail-account-configured-and-without-sim-card http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25418/i-lost-my-phone-but-need-to-find-its-imei-what-places-can-i-look http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28581/find-my-android-from-an-app

Comment: BTW: the a500 has built-in GPS, so Plan B will work if it's connected to the internet still. If not and the battery is empty, you're out of luck and have to search it the usual way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Google Account configured at your tablet try [Plan B](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb). You can install it throug Google Play store.

Comment: thanks for your help, but the thing is I already lost it, so there is point of installing it now cause i dont have it with me. Its already stolen and I need away to track it and get it back!                                                                      ---Thnx any further help would be highly appreciated.---

Comment: You can install it throug Google Play. Access the page and click install. The app will be installed remotely on your tablet.

Comment: well I'm not an expert on this, So can you explain how (instructions)! I dont have the tablet with me. So how could I go to google play? Thnxs

Comment: @nashita Access this [direct link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb) to the PLAN B application from Google Play Store. Press the install button and if your tablet is connected to the network, the application should install by itself. After the install, you'll get a map with GPS coordinates on your Gmail account.

Comment: @Zuul thank you sooo much. OK now i have a question does it have to battery and wifi connection cause my Acer  Android Tablet a500 Iconia Tab if fully out of charge and it defiantly not lost in my house so I dont think it has wifi connection. So will it still WORK?              Thank you

Comment: @nashita If there's no power, nothing can work! The only issue with this type of situations is that users have a small window of opportunity the locate the device. After the battery drain completely, there's only the old fashioned search method...

Comment: @Zuul ohhh OK.... Well um I think that the person who stole it bought a charge and charged it because I installed plan B but when I checked a day after it wasn't installed anymore, So I think that the person who has taken it keeps deleting the plan B. Although I may have installed it when it was dead! But I have a  question: Even if I get the location of it how could I get it? the reason for this is this person is a stranger and I totally don't know them.... I lost it Niagara Falls at a Pizza Hut. Please help and I heard that it has a GPS installed! PLEASE HELP, PLEASE AND THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @Zuul And also what is the old fashioned way? It probably is the worst way right? thanks for your help. ALSO READ THE COMMENT I POSTED BEFORE TO YOU! THANK YOU SOO MUCH!

Comment: @nashita When you "install" Plan B, do you get an email on your Google account with a map and GPS coordinates?

Comment: @Zuul well actually I didnt but maybe cause the battery is dead or maybe the person who stole it keeps deleting the plan B app if it is even possible! is it?.... I really need HELP! And also when i get a maps and GPS coordinated what do I do next, because the person who has is a total stranger and what if he/she doesn't give it do I contact Android Acer? PLEASE HELP THANKS SOOO MUCH! :)

Comment: @Zuul can you help me with the previous comment.